# How to publish a two-dimensional array msg with int8 type?

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I now have a two-dimensional array of size nxn where n < 10 with int8 or int16 type array elements. I need to publish this array to a topic. I defined my own msg header, a simple int8 type msg such as the following:

```
int8 num
```

Can I do something like this:
Let's say A is a two-dimensional array A = [1 2; 1 3];

```
ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<test1::int8>("Chatter", 1000);
pub.publish(A);
```

In the callback function of the subscriber:

```
void chatterCallback(const test1::num& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO(...);
}
```

Is there any problem with this approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67273/how-to-publish-a-two-dimensional-array-msg-with-int8-type?/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-07-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure whether the approach u have mentioned will work or not.

Since ROS currently supports declaration of only 1D array in custom message types you can do the following:

array1d.msg

`int8[] a;`

and then declare another message
array2d.msg

`array1d[] b;`

This will create vector inside a vector and can be used as 2d array.

Hope this helps...

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on 2013-07-14**:
what do you mean by declaring "array1d.msg"?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-14**:
Its just name of the message...

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-16**:
Read these if you haven't yet:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Messages
http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg

**Comment by [nimish](https://answers.ros.org/users/65058/nimish/) on 2020-12-21**:
Are you sure this idea of vector inside a vector works? I tried implementing this in my case for ROS action and I cannot read the message at the client. The result is an empty message.